# Content Assist Does Not Work

Tags: android, eclipse

I just have a small and simple question, the Content Assist for (xml and java) in Eclipse Kepler does not work. When I press ctrl-space the auto-assist does not appear.

my question is: how to activate the content assist?

[image]

Comment: what os do you use? what is your config of content assist?

Comment: I am using Windows Vista. See the attached Image.

Comment: I faced the same problem, solved it by installing eclipse and Android ADT Plugin manually instead of Android bundle.

Answer (score 0):

1. Restore defaults
2. Replace "prompt when these character are inserted" with <=:.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Comment: "2" isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: "2" will make it more powerful when typing

Answer (score 0):

As another answer mentioned, Restore Defaults on that Preference Page.  Then, go back to the editor and tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and see what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> is already assigned to do, if anything.  You may have to go to the Keys preference page and change the assigned key bindings (or also Restore Defaults).